# Multiple Primary Keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

When I execute "sp_help tableName" I see a constraint where it says 'Primary Key (clustered)', and it lists three columns under the header 'constraint_keys'.

Does that mean that any one of those column values will uniquely identify the row, or that the values of all three columns together uniquely identify the row?

Comment: all three are the primary key, sounds like you have composite primary key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that all three columns combine to make a unique row.  Any individual column can have duplicates as long as the combination is unique.

Answer (score 4):

All three together are the primary key.

This is similar in concept to a covering index that indexes multiple fields.

Answer (score 2):

It means all three will uniquely identify any particular entry.

For example, let's say that you've got an "orders" table, with the following fields:

**ORDERS:**
customerID PK
DateTime PK
OrderTotal

Since there could be multiple entries in the Orders table by the same customerID, you cannot use it alone to uniquely identify a single order. There also may be multiple orders that have taken place at the same time (from different custoemrs), so the DateTime field cannot be used alone.

However, combining the two fields will provide you with a way of uniquely identifying an individual entry.